# Error installing ubuntu server?

Tags: 14.04, server

My problem is the same as the one addressed in this thread.
[Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 install error: can't umount /media](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598110/ubuntu-server-14-04-2-install-error-cant-umount-media)

But the solution was given by the asker as he manually created a link between /cdrom and /media and i'm not sure how to do that. So if someone could tell me really quick because i'm kind of a noob to this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 install error: can't umount /media](http://askubuntu.com/questions/598110/ubuntu-server-14-04-2-install-error-cant-umount-media)

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out what the designation of your USB stick is and then during install you execute this command:
`mount -t auto /dev/sdxy /cdrom` where sdxy is the correct designation of your USB stick.

Example: let's say your USB stick is sde1 then the command is mount -t auto /dev/sde1 /cdrom

**disclaimer:** I've never tried this myself and to be honest I don't believe this will work. But you asked for it and this was reported as actually working somewhere.

Comment: thank you but my only problem really is how to execute a command during installation. I know in normal ubuntu its ctrl+alt+a number but im not sure how to do that in the ubuntu server installation.

Comment: So apparently you can boot from the live cd. In that case you choose for the option that is about 'try without installing'. Then you can invoke the terminal with ctrl+alt+ a number now you can execute your command. After that choose the other option that is about installing  ubuntu.